# Who, or what, are the "four living creatures", as introduced in Revelation 4:6,7 & 8?

Tags: revelation, symbolism, heaven

It would appear that the answer can hardly be found in the "Earthly" realm. The answer has to be found in the "Heavenly" realm, given the close relationship to the "Almighty", Himself, (not to mention the fact that John is actually seen to be in heaven when relating his story). But in what manner, is the thing? Symbolism is obviously at play here, but of what exactly??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Who, or what, are the "four living creatures", as introduced in Revelation 4:6,7 & 8?**

I have often wondered as to the significance of the "four living creatures" appearances, specifically with regard to the facial. What could they possibly be emblematic of. There are indeed similarities to the four creatures of **Ezekiel 1**. Even though the **cherubim** analogy would seem to have some merit, in that they may have a supernatural mobility in their *cultic* role as throne bearers of God, I think there is more here than meets the eye, or should I say **eyes**. Let's take the following bible verses for instance:

> **Luke 21:25 & 26, NASB**
> And there will be *signs* in sun and moon and *stars*, and upon the earth dismay among nations, in perplexity at the roaring of the sea and waves, men fainting from fear and the expectation of the things which are coming upon the world; for the powers of the *heavens* will be shaken.

Also, brackets/boldness mine,

> **Isaiah 19:19 & 20, NASB**.
> In that day there will be an *altar* (pyramid) to the Lord in the midst of the land of Egypt, and a *pillar* (monument/testimony) to the Lord near its border. And it will become a *sign* and a *witness* to the Lord of hosts in the land of Egypt; for they will cry to the Lord because of oppressors , and He will send them a Savior and a Champion, and He will deliver them.
>
> **Job 38:3-7, NASB**.
> "Now gird up your loins like a man, and I will ask you, and you instruct Me! Where were you when I **laid the foundation of the earth!** Tell Me if you have an understanding, who set it's **measurements**, since you know? Or who stretched the line on it? On what were its **bases sunk**? Or who laid its **cornerstone**, when the **morning stars** sang together, and all the **sons of God** shouted for joy?
>
> **Rev, 21:12, NASB**.
> It (heavenly holy city of Jerusalem), had a great and high wall, with twelve gates, and at the gates **twelve angels**; and names *were* written on them, which are *those* of the **twelve tribes** of the **sons of Israel**.

It is widely accepted that the verses from Luke, here depicted, may well not only encapsulate 70 AD but may also refer to the "End Times". It is not *as* widely accepted that the verses from Isaiah may well indeed encapsulate, the **Great Pyramid of Giza**. The Revelation verse will be gone into in due course, within this presentation.

However, the verses within **Job 38: 3-7**, especially where I have **highlighted**, would seem to be a *veiled* (but yet future) inference to this **pyramid**. See, also, **Jeremiah 32:20** ... *who has set signs and wonders in the land of Egypt* ...

Verse 7 is particularly interesting. Here we see a reference to the *first stars* (of creation) and the (angelic) *sons of God* in universal praise of God's worldly creation. Could the *first* stars (of the creation) be, also, a cryptic reference to the **"four living creatures"**, God's **cherubim** perhaps. Ellicott, in his bible commentary on this verse, makes an interesting inference (emphasizes mine):

> **The morning stars.** - The context seems to suggest that by the **stars** are meant the **angels** entrusted with their **guardianship**, from whence Milton has borrowed his conceptions. The *magnificent* **sublimity** of the expression and the **thought** needs no comment.

Matthew Poole's commentary, is descriptive of actual stars - "morning stars", that is ... *because of their excellent lustre and glory, for which they are called "angels of light"*.

I have taken the liberty, above, of italicizing the words: signs, stars, heavens, altar, sign and witness. More on these to follow. But for now, some "background" information:-

**Precession of the Equinoxes, a 26,000 year cycle**

> What we call the "astrological ages" are a way of interpreting history by dividing time into chunks of about **2160 years**, each one being associated with a particular sign of the zodiac. By this scheme, we're currently in the "Age of Pisces" and soon to enter the "Age of Aquarius", although some argue we're already there. This disagreement gives us our first clue that the "Ages" are less than straightforward and not remotely "scientific". However, there is a *real* phenomenon at work behind the idea. The "Ages" come about due to the **precession of the equinoxes**, and the *separation* of the tropical zodiac *from* the constellations.
>
> The zodiac is a band of space that sits either side of the ecliptic - the path the sun appears to take as we orbit around it, and where the moon lines up with the sun causing eclipses (hence the name).Western astrology uses the "tropical zodiac" which is aligned with the seasons in the northern hemisphere, and starts at (0) Aries [mid point of Aries to be more precise], marking the **vernal point**, otherwise known as the **spring equinox**.
>
> So *precession* measures the [apparent] *retrograde* motion of the **spring equinox** as it [apparently, but not definitively] moves along the ecliptic and backwards through the zodiac. After about 1000 years, or so, the **vernal point/equinox** proves to be in a different zodiacal area.
>
> It takes about **72 years** for the equinox to move just 1 degree through the zodiac, so each sign of 30 degrees takes 2160 years. The whole cycle is then completed in about 25,920 years.

The above, which is somewhat condensed, is taken from the Astro Journal ... The Age of Aquarius and Precession of the Equinoxes, by Jessica Davidson, 01/02/2021 [with a slight alteration, by me, to the last sentence of the penultimate paragraph, for, as it was, it didn't make sense. All this type of brackets [ ] mine also]. Stay with me!! This is confusing, I know, but try and stay with me to the end, as I, myself, found all this *truly* insightful, to say the least.

**The Revelation of the Pyramids (Documentary)**

> An *apocryphal* view on the pyramids, starting in awe at the amazing achievement of the Pharaonic architecture and sculpture, mostly at **Giza**, given Cheops'  (Khufu's) pyramids size, weight, incredibly precise carving, four pairs of slightly shifted half sides, stunningly precisely measured shapes and symmetry. Then it questions and challenges conventional Egyptology beliefs, which it calls unproven, or even impossible to verify, such as the absence of machines, a dwarf duration of only 20 years, or even accidental equinox-orientation. Next it elaborates the theory that other major pyramid technology sites in pre Columbian America, Easter island and China, *can't* coincidentally lie on two lines intersecting at Giza, even if not contemporaneous and without known contacts in their ages, and have several improbable things in common, like some of their cultures. Elaborate mathematical theories and measurements indicate the Egyptians must have known some astronomy, like **pi** and the **golden number**, maybe even the **meter**, and such knowhow may even have been *secretly* passed on!!!

Taken from the introductory narrative for the above documentary, by **Jacques Grimault**, who also wrote the book of the same title, and which is narrated by Patrice Booyard, now available on Vimeo. The documentary goes on to speculate that maybe the *secret* was passed on by a lost civilization, or even aliens, but then, to their credit, juxtaposed that it all may just have been **God**.

**Specific Purpose**

> The builders of the Great Pyramid, left nothing to chance. They apparently were able to measure the earth; they designed their scaled model after it, in the shape of a pyramid, in which scientific parameters were featured; they had lined up their *familial* location/archaeological sites on a strip as long as the equator - but at 30 degrees from the traditional equator - such as: Easter Island; Machu Picchu; Ollantaytambo; Paracas civilization; the Dogon country and Mohanjo-daro. The builders also seemed to be familiar with the speed of light and even incorporated the rotation of the earth. All to a **specific purpose**, such as to benefit a *future* civilization on earth ... **ours** ... a message of the utmost significance.

**Critical astronomical cycle of our planet**

> If one picks a star in the sky, it will be one degree off 72 years later. It will take almost 26,000 years for this star to accomplish a complete orbit. The 26,000 year span represents a precession of the equinoxes cycle. To precisely locate the earth, and the universe, modern astronomers use the zodiac constellations, which are a simple means to observe the positions of the **stars**. The constellations targeted by the **Sphinx's eyes**, for instance, have shifted over time. The **pyramidion** found at the foot of the Sneferu Red Pyramid, **a corner stone if you will**, was providing another bit of significant information. Its perimeter was precisely 12 cubits long and the presence of **pi** referred to a circle, a 12 zone cycle, a zodiac.

The above narratives were taken from the *voice over* of the aforementioned documentary, edited slightly in the interests of brevity.See link: https://watchdocumentaries.com/the-revelation-of-the-pyramids/

**Corner Stone**

> **Acts 4:11, NASB**.
> He, (Jesus) is the stone which was rejected by you, the builders, but which became the very corner stone.
>
> **Mark 12:10 & 11, NASB**.
> "Have you not even read the scripture:
> THE STONE WHICH THE BUILDERS REJECTED,
> THIS BECAME THE CHIEF CORNER STONE: THIS CAME ABOUT FROM THE LORD, AND IT IS MARVELOUS IN OUR EYES?
>
> **Psalm 118:22 & 23, NASB**.
> The stone which the builders rejected has become the chief corner stone. This is the Lord's doing; it is marvelous in our eyes.

Israel was the stone that the builders of *civilization* had rejected, but God made his people the cornerstone of his plan for the world (now *spiritual* Israel, it would seem). The apostles referred to Jesus also, as the stone that was rejected, and he is now the all important **cornerstone of God's kingdom**.

**Zodiacal Signs**

> The pyramid of Giza's **four** angles refer to **four** zodiacal *signs* **TAURUS, LEO, SCORPIO and AQUARIUS**. In the ancient world Scorpio was represented by an **EAGLE** and Aquarius by an **ANGEL**, as it occurs on the front of our cathedrals. **Four** *stars* are assigned to those **four** *signs*. Among the shiniest ones, they used to be called the **four guardians of heaven**, are **ALDEBARAN**, in the Taurus constellation; **REGULUS** in Leo; **ANTARES** in Scorpio, and **FORMALHAUT**, on top of Pisces today but formerly in Aquarius, before modern astronomers proceeded to some modifications. Those *stars* seem to keep the same position between themselves and have been used as *steady* reference points through time. Looking down (from space) on top of the Giza pyramid, we have from bottom left to top right, the Taurus/Scorpio axis, formerly known as the Taurus/Eagle axis, that Babylonians depicted by a winged bull. Then we have from bottom right to top left, the Leo/Aquarius axis, or Leo/Angel axis, according to the ancient calling, whose representation happens to be right here on the Giza Plateau, in the manner of the **Sphinx**, a man's head on a lions body....

The whole sites geometry then allows for some *magical* geometrical confluence lining, which can only be explained properly by watching the documentary video.

> .... The Giza plateau then takes on the appearance of an astronomical clock, whose style was those **four** steady reference points; the **four** *stars*. This clock's needle, the Sphinx's  *gaze* (if you will), turns around itself, in a bit less than 26,000 years and enables to point precisely the earth's position in this big cycle. The starting point being Regulus ....

Again one would need to see the video.

> .... in the Leo constellation. When the Sphinx's *eyes*, will precisely *gaze* at Regulus, or when the Sphinx's axis will be lined up with the Leo/Aquarius' axes, then a new "precession of the equinoxes" cycle will start anew.

Taken, as best as I can, with emphasizes mine, again from the voice over (which is in a French accent) in the documentary video.

**CONCLUSION**

The video goes on to talk about "climatical changes", as a result of the "precession of the equinoxes". For, after all, the glacier and heat cycles are in sync with the earth's orbital parameters. But, let's stop here with the science of it all. The philosophical hypothesis that I have *tried* to evidence here (this hasn't been easy), is that maybe, just maybe, the **"four living creatures"**, as portrayed in the heavens, around God's throne, with their distinctive faces and full of eyes all around, and within, may be depicting, the **four** steady reference points; the **four** stars, and their respective zodiacal signs, that incorporate the **Lion**, the young **Bull**, **Man** and *flying* **Eagle**, around the **Great Pyramid of Giza**...

**OR**,

...they could be depicting the four heads of the **12 tribes of Israel**!!!! Now this is interesting....

If you were to *now* read **Ezekiel, chapter 1** - remember I referred to this in the very first paragraph of this exposition - you will notice that the image has four faces: that of a **lion**; an **ox**; a **man**; and an **eagle**. These faces represent the **Four tribes of Israel**, led by:-

> **Judah**, whose symbol was a **lion**.
> **Ephraim**, whose symbol was an **ox**.
> **Reuben**, whose symbol was a **man**.
> **Dan**, whose symbol was an **eagle**.

Taken from an article entitled **"Who is America"**, by one Linda Watson, an historian, which although centers around the fate of the tribes of **Ephraim & Manasseh**, does also make reference to the **12 tribes of Israel** and their four respective splits, encompassing three tribes in each. Then, Judah for instance, along with the *principals* of Issachar and Zebulun (three persons) would be representative of **three pairs of arms (6 in all)** - a reference to the - **three pairs of wings** - perhaps, attributed to each of the **"four living creatures"**. Also, encampment of the tribes, were to the East; West; South and North, respectively. With the Levitical priests, along with Moses; Aaron and sons, not to mention the **Tabernacle Tent**, being central to all. The **"throne in heaven"** scene, in **Rev, 4:1-11**, immediately comes to mind, even though the tribal *makeup* is slightly, but not exponentially, different.

**NB**

Further interesting facts:

**Ark of the Covenant** dimensions are an even multiple of the dimension of the **King's Chamber** of the Great Pyramid, the granite sarcophagus could even be an earthly reference to the ark.

Sir Isaac Newton discovered the sacred Jewish inch measurement within the pyramid. The result was that he dedicated the rest of his life to Bible Study.

The pyramid depicts **True North** at time of it's erection.

Pyramid is situated in **geographical center** of the land surface of the whole world, on the equal surface projection. Centralized in the Northern Hemisphere, the longitude (from Greenwich) is 30 degrees East. Latitude is, even, 30 degrees North.

Finally, and probably most importantly, it is said that the **Well Shaft**, within the pyramid, may be depicting: Escape from *evil world* by acknowledging the **"RANSOM SACRIFICE"**. But then, maybe we should leave that for another time ....

Comment: I cannot see how any of this is even vaguely Biblical - 26000 years is unbiblical, Zodiac signs are unbiblical, the great pyramid of Giza is unbiblical, etc.  However, it is qyite imaginative and creative.

Comment: @Dottard - I guess my thoughts with regard to the word "biblical" - of relating to, or being in accord with the Bible - encompass more of a fullness of meaning. Astrology, may not exactly be Astronomy, but it can be relative, horoscopes and palm reading and the like, aside for sure.  *"Let now the astrologers, those who prophesy by the stars, those who predict by the new moons, stand up and save you from what will come upon you ..."* **Isaiah 47:13**. God is saying that astrologers will be able to give accurate info' about future events, but this won't save rulers who oppose God....tbc...

Comment: If God created everything, then he created the 26,000 year cycle, of which to this point "mankind" has only experienced the first 6,000 years (3 ages). To my mind, and not just mine, the **Great Pyramid of Giza** is indeed of *great* biblical importance, it's just not part of Christianity's mainstream thinking yet. It's just like an heavenly angelic messenger, only it's an earthly message, from the absolute center of the earth, the "Meridian", after all, passes right through it. But, thank you for the...quite imaginative and creative...line.

Comment: @Dottard - https://medium.com/belover/astrology-in-the-bible-5d4abecac741 Please, if you will, check this out.

Comment: I am familiar with this creative eisegetic none-sense.  The link was full of factual errors.  This site is not the place to debate this so I will refrain.  The worst problem with this astrology-based material is that it distracts from the central message of Jesus.

Comment: @Dottard - Having just got back from my venture abroad, I have now added further content to my answer, in an attempt to convey further understanding, in light of further study. I can understand your concern with astrology based material and the sampling I pointed you to, may not have been the best. The central message of Jesus aside, I think the central message of **God**, as pertains to the earthly, rather than the heavenly, is extremely well depicted within, and around, the **Great Pyramid of Giza**. I just can't stress/express this enough. The written word, however, is still the ultimate.

Comment: I wish the answer were more brief but I'm upvoting it because it taught me something new - about Giza and the four zodiacal signs. I also agree that knowing non-Jewish cultural parallels is sometimes very helpful. On the other hand I wouldn't rule out several other symbolic 4s.  I do disagree with you when you say that allusions the cherubim of Ezekiel are not helpful. My answer suggests 4 realms of God's sovereignty. Based on Occam's razor, this is the one I prefer.

Comment: In a sense, ancient history of the region provides biblical context and might have shaped prototype patriachal Israel as it emerged from the late bronze age as heritage.   So cultures of  Egypt, Mesopotamia, and Greece provide context of what Israel was set to leave behind in its faith and culture.  It's well worth understanding IMHO, because if nothing else some of it would have been in Israel's legend.  Astrology was pervasive in various cultures, even if rightly banished from scripture, though stars  and omens still had importance and symbolism.  Because of this I upvoted it.

Comment: @Thermion - Well said. Thank you for taking the time. Hopefully you watched the "linked" documentary. I've watched it a dozen or more times and after every time I glean something new. I highly recommend it. You will never look at the Great Pyramid in the same way ever again.

Answer (score 4):

The 4 living creatures, first introduced in Rev. 4:6-9, are the fourth aspect of what is before God's throne in heaven. There is not space here to preface the answer with the three other aspects, helpful though that would be.  But the number 4 is too significant to ignore, and pertains to your query about these 4 living creatures being in heaven, so not earthly.

Ah, but ***the symbolic meaning of the number 4 in scripture pertains to the Earth and speaks of earthly things***, e.g. the 4 chariots of Zechariah ch. 6 going to the north, south, east and west on the Earth, with the 4 spirits going forth from God's throne. Earthly creatures are depicted on the 4 faces of the 4 living creatures before God's throne; lion, calf, man, eagle. Here is an explanation of what they represent, as given in the book below:

> "These represent the whole Creation, just as four is the number of the
> earth. They are full of eyes before and behind. Behind, their
> intelligent sight beholds all that was cherished in the garden of
> Eden, and in the entire Creation. Before lies a new Creation, and
> *they* see it, and pertain to it, though now they await the end of *this* world, and the consummation of all things...
>
> If they had wings, this was for heavenly movement: that is, the
> heavenly ascent of Creation's concepts. If full of eyes *within*, that
> is of the Holy Ghost, and, glorifying Christ, signifies the creatures'
> innate intelligence that *they belong to him who was in heaven, who
> had been rejected on earth*. They corresponded inwardly with the mind,
> and the right, of God in and to his own creation of the earth and its
> fulness.
>
> Such creatures were first named - but not described - in Genesis 3:24,
> after fallen man was expelled for ever, when the earth was cursed, and
> the world had begun its mad and ever-accelerating career downwards
> through time into greater and greater evil, and more and more
> ingenious evil imaginations. But all this time the symbol of the
> cherubim stood at the gate of the lost paradise. Now 'cherubim' means
> 'grasped'. Man had let it all go. But God had let go nothing. It was
> 'grasped'.
>
> Those creatures, representing God's grasp upon the nature of the
> Creation, and of the creature, despite man's having brought *this*
> Creation and *its* creatures to perpetual ruin in the Fall, I say,
> these cherubim appeared in the tabernacle. They also appeared in the
> temple. In the holy place, God signified that nothing of *his* was
> lost, whatever *man* had relinquished.
>
> Something of the like appeared also to the prophet Ezekiel, called by
> him 'living beings', associated with the glory of God, yet evidently
> earthly creatures with heavenly movement laying a claim to a dominion
> which man had lost, a Creation beyond that which man had irrevocably
> ruined, and a world and age that could never be answered by that which
> is present. For God had let nothing go: the throne of world dominion
> was claimed in his testimony set amidst a disobedient and rebellious
> people."  *The Revelation of Jesus Christ*, pp.101-102, John Metcalfe

The author then speaks of Isiah and the seraphim and the wheels, with much more about the cherubim. But I will conclude this lengthy quote with just two final points he makes:

> "It is a question of divine movement, it is the whole question of
> movement in relation to Creation. All is lifted up off the earth and
> caught up into heaven, as though the fallen chaos that actually exists
> down here were forgotten... When John describes the new Creation in
> the closing chapters of Revelation those creatures appear no more.
> Because then fallen man and the present world will have passed away in
> judgment. But every thought of God, all his mind in Creation for
> Christ, will have come to pass for eternity. The time for mysterious
> symbols is over. Reality comes with eternity." (*Ibid*. p. 104)

I hope this will give the start of some insight into ***your query, "Symbolism is obviously at play here, but of what exactly?"***

Comment: Not sure why I didn't comment on this A, as I try to comment on all A's, given to my own Q's, below being case in point. I did, however, upvote it and on the very day that you answered. I just thought that Metcalfe didn't quite nail it, although he did make some good points for sure. Obviously, I've attempted to nail it myself and apparently, it would seem, came up short. I found it very difficult to answer, even went out on a limb trying and may well have gotten out there in left field. Nevertheless, I've now linked a video, which may be of interest to you, seeing as it's about the GP of G.

Comment: @Olde English   Noted. I would just add that nobody is going to "nail it" this side of eternity! Not least because there's a significant point in the Revelation where John is told not to write down what he heard 'the seven thunders' utter.- Rev. 10:1-4

Comment: Aahh, yes!! How can we *truly* know where we are in the overall scheme of things. We need to carry on believing in, not to mention, have understanding of, the **"Ransom Sacrifice"**, which enables us to be heard, particularly when being *truly* repentant of our sins, and have "faith" that all will turn out right for all those that have the *"spirit"* of the Almighty and His son, within them. Yes, I know you, being *trinitarian*, would word that last bit differently. If you haven't already watched the "Documentary", I *highly* recommend that you do, but if you do, watch with an **open** mind.

Answer (score 2):

Since they are in the company of the "elders", I suggest first looking at the symbolism of the elders in order to gain an insight into the symbolism of their companions.

The elders are there as the symbolic leaders and representatives of the saints. The relevant O.T. parallel is Exodus ch24 vv9-11. On that occasion, Moses and Aaron, Nadab and Abihu "and seventy of the elders of Israel" went up the mountain to see "The God of Israel". What they saw, of course, was an image accommodated to their understanding, which is the only way that men can "see God". For "no man has ever seen God", in the true sense (John ch1 v18). An important detail of this image is that "there was under his feet as it were a pavement of sapphire stone, like the very heaven for clearness" (v10, RSV). This detail is shared by the mobile-throne vision of Ezekiel ("There was the likeness of a firmament, shining like crystal"- Ezekiel ch1 v22). It is also shared with the Revelation ch4 scene ("before the throne there is as it were a sea of glass like crystal" v6). These are three scenes of a similar type.

On that basis, I maintain that the elders in Revelation ch4 have the same function as the elders of Exodus ch24. They are the delegated representatives of God's people, the saints.

Coming now to the four living creatures, we see that we have the figures of a lion, and eagle, and an ox, each of which is a leading species in its own sphere (animals, birds, domesticated creatures). There is also a figure of a man, a species designated as having "dominion" over the living creatures of the earth in Genesis ch1 v28. So, on the analogy of the elders, I suggest their symbolism is that they represent all the living creatures of the world.

At the same time, there also seems to be a sense in which the living creatures in Ezekiel ch1 and this chapter represent "the four winds", which might be supposed, in the original concept, to be holding up God's throne in the clouds. They call forth the four horsemen in ch6, and the devastation of ch6 is associated with the "four winds" in ch7 vv1-3. That is, the four angels hold back the four winds; the next angel then explains (for our benefit) that this "holding back" amounts to a postponement (for the time being) of the further harm that could be done to the earth. We might compare God's threat in Jeremiah to send "the four winds of heaven" to scatter Elam (Jeremiah ch49 v36).

In short, they seem to be combining two sets of symbolism; "the four winds" of God's power at work, and "the living creatures of the world at large".

Comment: The elders here do indeed represent the saints, as you say. They would also seem to represent the leaders of groups of 6000, making for a priesthood of 144,000 to stand on the heavenly Mount Zion, ready to rule (note the crowns) with the Lamb, Jesus Christ. See **Rev, 14:1-4**. However, this is not the focus of the **Q**. The "living creatures", as depicted, are indeed representative of leading species. The man, here depicted, being a leading angel, *of a sort*. The symbolism, however, I feel is much more than you ascertain. As for "the four winds" *angelic* sense, that's something else IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding any passage in Revelation is to find which passage it alludes to, usually in the OT.  In the case of the four living creatures, there is no doubt that it alludes to the four creatures of Ezekiel 1.  Note the following similarities:

- four faces of a man, lion, ox, eagle
- covered in eyes
- in the midst and around the throne of God
- had four (Eze 1) or six (Rev 4) wings each
- associated with fire and torches
- above the throne of God is a rainbow

[Aside: The Ark of the Covenant appears to be a representation/caricature of this throne scene because it has two cherubim surrounding the throne of God (the mercy seat), and augmented by two more cherubim on the temple wall of the most holy place see Ex 25:18-22, 37:7, 1 Kings 6:27, 32, 35, 8:7, 2 Chron 3:7, 10, 11, 5:8, Eze 10:1, 9, 19, Heb 9:5, etc.]

Thus, four cherubim appear to be integral to the functioning of God's throne.  In Eze 1 & 10 it appears these living creatures are cherubim whose job is to transport the throne wherever God wishes to go.  That is, no description of the throne of God is really without those four living creatures also known as cherubim.  See also:

- 1 Sam 4:4 - So the people sent men to Shiloh, and they brought back the ark of the covenant of the LORD Almighty, who is **enthroned between the cherubim**. And Eli’s two sons, Hophni and Phinehas, were there with the ark of the covenant of God.
- 2 Sam 6:2 - He and all his men went to Baalah in Judah to bring up from there the ark of God, which is called by the Name, the name of the LORD Almighty, who is **enthroned between the cherubim** on the ark.
- 2 Kings 19:15 - And Hezekiah prayed before the LORD: “O LORD, God of Israel, **enthroned between the cherubim**, You alone are God over all the kingdoms of the earth. You made the heavens and the earth.
- Ps 80:1 - For the choirmaster. To the tune of “The Lilies of the Covenant.” A Psalm of Asaph. Hear us, O Shepherd of Israel, who leads Joseph like a flock; You who sit **enthroned between the cherubim**, shine forth
- Ps 99:1 - The LORD reigns; let the nations tremble! He is **enthroned above the cherubim**; let the earth quake!

Thus, it appears that the description of God on His throne supported/between the cherubim, may have some literal elements to it.

Comment: There is no mistaking that the *four* "living creatures" allude to the four creatures in **Ezekiel 1**, the similarities are unmistakable. The **cherubim** may have a supernatural mobility in their *cultic* role as throne bearers of God, but I'm looking for an answer that concentrates on how these *presumptive* **cherubim** are depicted, particularly as pertains to their facial caricatures.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - I am not sure how to answer except to say that is simply the depiction of the Throne of God and its constant attendants.

Comment: I have a theory, as to what the "caricatures" represent, but *before* putting forward my own response, to my own question, I wanted to see what thoughts might be out there in **BH** land first. Stay tuned....The composition involved, in order to answer competently, I'm not looking forward to, but hopefully, once completed, it can be well received.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - there is an early (unbiblical) theory that the four faces represented the four evangelists, Matthew, Mark, Luke and John as these are the regular symbols for each of them.  I have also heard another (unbiblical) theory that they represent the "four character" types of the saved.  Unfortunately, there is no Biblical basis for any such theory.

Comment: @Dottard Do you have a breakdown/post disproving the two theories?

Comment: @O.J. - it is not necessary to disprove a theory that has no Biblical basis.  If something simply uses Biblical language but has no actual textual support, it is unbiblical.  For example, Why not say the four faces represent, the USA (eagle), Russia (bear), England (lion) and Australia (human), or any other fantastic theory?

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate that the question asks about the 'four living creatures'
as I agree that that is the correct translation. (Not 'beasts'.)

The following is an extract from my book 'The Cherubim of Glory'
and all is relevant to the question.

---

In Christ, who is exalted, in humanity, above every name that is
named - who is exalted above the heaven to the very throne of
the Father - in him, and under his Headship, is a new humanity
which is risen out of the old and is seated in the heavenlies with
Christ. Such a humanity is that which is according to God’s
eternal purpose. In such humanity - in sonship - does the Father
delight.

This living - expressed fourfold - is seen round the throne.

It is thoroughly wrong to translate zown, in Chapter Four, as ‘beast’,
thus causing confusion with therion, ‘beast’, in Chapter 13:1, and
thereafter, which beasts are associated with the Drakon, another
matter altogether.

The four living, they should be called, and they are around
throne in company with the twenty four elders, all the wisdom
come out of Israel and come out of Apostleship. Together, the
living and the wisdom combine and are seen again as the
hundred and forty four thousand, the full complement of both
testaments multiplied in divine activity.

There is another hint of what is here seen in the two angels, in
white, which Mary saw in the sepulchre. They are described as
‘sitting’, kathezomai. Downsitting, kata, but with the word zoe,
life, added. I take this to imply sitting upright, either literally or
metaphorically. Six times is the word used and it is instructive to
see of whom it is used. But here I see an emphasis on living.

Seated, in that the attitude is one of rest, in sabbath, yet not inactive. Lively, quick, for all that they are ‘dwonseated’.

And here also is a hint of what cherubim convey. The angelic two
sit at the head and feet of where the body of Jesus had lain, very
reminiscent of cherubim atop the ark. Rightly seen, the
sepulchre is where the ark completes its journey. Then - he is not
here; he is risen !

The full complement are seen again, an exceeding great
multitude which no man number. Angels minister to these,
holding back the winds of final judgment till all be gathered and
sealed, Revelation 7:3. These angels stand about the throne, and
they are about the elders and, within, are both about the living.
All fall upon their faces before the throne and worship God,
saying, Amen: Blessing and glory and wisdom and thanksgiving
and honour and power and might be unto God for ever and ever.Amen.

Cherubim are an abstract concept. I do not believe they are,
strictly speaking, a representation of the people of God in
themselves. Nor do I believe they are a representation, as such,
of angelic beings or angelic activity itself. Nor yet do I accept that
they are an expression of animal life, as such.

I believe that cherubim are an abstract concept representing something in God. It is a matter of God’s purpose.

It is that which he purposes in everlasting. It is that which, ultimately, will
express God in a substantial creation. That which is within God -
his desire, his purpose - shall, through first creation, redemption
and new creation, be fully expressed in the manifesting of God
through humanity.

But the first humanity failed of that purpose. Hence redemption
in Christ. But redemption in Christ does not re-instate the first
humanity. Redemption in Christ brings in a new humanity - in
Christ - of which he is the Head. He also is the firstbegotten from
the dead. He is also the *Prototokos* - the first token, the firstfruits
of investment.

In Christ is the restitution of all things, Acts 3:21.

---

Reproduced from 'The Cherubim of Glory' (pp 11-123) by Nigel Johnstone
published by Belmont Publications. The book is available in PDF form
on the website of Belmont Publications. See my profile for the details.

Comment: With all due respect, I see a lot of *flowery* prose here, but I fail to see how this answers the question of the symbolism of the *four* "living creatures" and what might they, themselves, *truly* represent, if indeed we are talking about a **who**, as opposed to a **what**.

Comment: @OldeEnglish I agree with your question statement 'symbolism is at play'. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The spiritual world is perceived subjectively, so visions of the four living creatures and other angelic beings may differ. John of Patmos' vision is certainly related to that of Ezekiel. It basically agrees with Ezek. 1 but not with Ezek. 10. One of John's creatures has the face of an ox where Ezek. 10 speaks of the face of a cherub. In addition, Ezekiel describes each cherub having four faces, while John seems to describe four creatures, each with a different face.

Ezekiel 10:14

> Each living creature had four faces: the first a cherub, the second a
> human being, the third a lion, the fourth an eagle.

Revelation 4:

> The first creature resembled a lion, the second was like a calf, the
> third had a face like that of a human being, and the fourth looked
> like an eagle in flight.

To summarize: In Ezekiel 10's vision, the four faces are 1) cherub 2) human 3) lion and 4) eagle. In John's vision the faces are 1) lion 2) calf 3) human and 4) eagle. In other words, Ezekiel sees a calf (or ox) while John sees the face of a cherub.  To complicate the matter, Ezek. 41:18 portrays the cherubim as each having not four, but two faces, as depicted in Ezekiel's vision of the restored Temple.

[image]

The question arises as to what the "face of a cherub" looked like in Ezekiel 10's vision. For this we may turn to artifacts left by other semitic cultures. The creature pictured above - with the face of a king, the body of a lion, and eagle's wings - was discovered in the ancient Assyrian city of Nimrud (located in modern Iraq) and dates for the 8th or 7th centuries B.C. Other sphynx-like winged creatures have been found elsewhere in the area. We cannot know for certain that this is what Ezekiel described as "the face of a cherub" but since he presumes that the reader knows what such a face looks like, there was probably some well known visible referent. In other words, the face of a cherub was probably sphynx-like, which would also explain why it could be described as a human face in Ezek. 1 and Rev. 4.

**Symbolism**. In terms of what the four faces represent, there are many opinions. A fairly simple and likely one is that they symbolize four domains of God's sovereignty. The lion represents wild animals; man represents humanity; the ox or calf represents domestic animals, and the eagle represents birds. If we substitute Ezekiel's cherub for John's ox, then the four realms would be angelic beings (cherub), humans (man), land animals (lion) and flying animals (eagle). Other interpretations are certainly possible, but this one, emphasizing God's sovereignty over all, is hard to argue against.

Comment: Well done! Your explanation as to Ezekiel's cherub would appear to have merit. + 1.

Comment: Having been in jail, so to speak, for the last 7 days, for stepping out of line with another poster, instead of "flagging" the poster, I am now back, and on the advice of "Moderation" have now edited my own answer here, which is now a *fuller* and better referenced exposition, and with even more (gasp) material. It may now be too long for most members here, but hopefully less confusing. Nevertheless, I just reread your answer here and I had forgotten the "cherub for ox" differential. Thinking about my added material, I wonder if the new "makeup" of the 12 tribes can explain the differential.

Comment: When all is said and done, keep in mind that all 4 "living creatures" are actually "cherubs" in their own right, consequently, one can presumably also have - cherub for man; cherub for lion; and cherub for eagle. They are all still collectively "cherubim". Even though Ez, 10, speaks of a cherub, instead of ox/bull/calf, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's not still depicting of an ox/bull/calf. The fact that John's "cherubs" go back to the same as described in Ez, 1, would seem to be factual confirmation. As for the "Millennium" scene, in EZ, 41:18,19, IMO the man/lion faces depict Jesus.